# How many child processes are created?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, nested-loops

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
fork();
```

How many child processes are created in the above code ?

---

**My attempt :**

I first solved the inner loop, and got total 32 processes in which 31 are child processes and 1 parent process.

Then, I went for outer loop which loops 5 times, thus producing 31 * 5 = 155 child processes.

---

Have I got this right ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     fork();
```

For such kind of situation the total no of processes created is always `2^n - 1` as `fork()` will get called by `n` time.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
     fork();
```

For this double `for-loop`, `fork()` gets called by `n^2` times, Hence total no of processes created will be,

```
2^(n^2) - 1
```

What is important for such questions is to calculate the no of times your `fork()` gets called.

For you case `n=5` so total no of child processes will be `2^25 - 1`.